# In NginX what means location ^~

Tags: php, nginx, htpasswd

If I'm not wrong,
`location = / {}` means "only the / folder, not the files inside, not the subfolders"
`location ~ / {}` means "the / folder, all the files inside, all the subfolders and their subfiles"
But what it means:
`location ^~ / {}`?
I found this configuration in the web, but I wasn't able to google an answer.
I found it in a tutorial while I was trying to protect with htpasswd a folder and everything inside of it. However `location ~ /` did the job, while even if `location ^~ /` protected everything as well, it did not let the php pages to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location):

> If the longest matching prefix location has the “^~” modifier then regular expressions are not checked.

So, if the location matches / location, then locations using regex aren't evaluated. This causes the effect you described, that is, PHP scripts stop working, because PHP scripts are generally defined using a regex location block.